# TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am new in web development, i am trying to hit an random image url generator API and trying to show image on screen.
i am getting the response from API but while passing the url to img variable i am getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
var img = document.querySelector("#photo");
function c(){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
method = "GET",
url = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = async function () {

if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
var url = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
img.src == url; <!-- I am getting error at this line-->
}
};
xhr.send();
}
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dog app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to dog photo app</h1>
            <img src="https:\/\/images.dog.ceo\/breeds\/waterdog-spanish\/20180723_185544.jpg" id="photo" alt=""><br>
                <form>
            <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="c()" value="click me">
                </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried that still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

   
function c(){
 var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
var img = document.querySelector("#photo");

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
method = "GET",
url = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = async function () {

if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
var url = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
img.src = url; <!-- I am getting error at this line-->
}
};
xhr.send();
}
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dog app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to dog photo app</h1>
            <img src="https:\/\/images.dog.ceo\/breeds\/waterdog-spanish\/20180723_185544.jpg" id="photo" alt=""><br>
                <form>
            <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="c()" value="click me">
                </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just replacethe `==` with `=` while assigning `url` to `img`
and move

```
 var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    var img = document.querySelector("#photo");
```

inside the `c()` function and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You executed `var img = document.querySelector("#photo");` before the image existed in the HTML. (It is defined *below* your JS code.

Moving the declarations of `btn` and `img` inside `function c() { ... }` will fix your issue, because all the HTML elements will exist.

```js
function c(){
    // Declarations have been added here
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    var img = document.querySelector("#photo");

    // Rest of the code
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    // ...
```

Comment: tried but now getting:  **Dog app.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received**.

Answer (score 0):

You typed

```
img.src == url;
```

If you want to assign the value of `url` to `img.src`, use only one `=` sign. `==` would mean checking if the value of `img.src` and `url` are the same. @HeySora's answer is also relevant; you need the script to run after the html element exists.